# Making an element display like it was an another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been thinking if it is possible to make an element that looked like another element that I've styled before.

For example:

I have a div:

```
div {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #555;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

And I have a button that has no style in it.

button:

```
button {}
```

Edited part of this question:
Is it possible to make the button looked like it was the div that I made before? Without using classes or grouping elements to one another. And without copying the css style of the div to button?

Comment: why dont you use classes instead?

Comment: Do you mean, you want a javascript code that copies all the style information from div to button?

Answer (score 2):

You can group the styles together using comma.

```
div, button {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #555;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

otherwise you will have to use classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to  make the button look-like the div on the click of something what you could do is. Write this is javascript document.getElementById("id of your button").style.whatever style you need to change. For each styling tags like border or colour you would have to write a seperate DOM for it.